# String a Date JavaScript

Tags: javascript

tengo el siguiente string: "1476154800000" quiero convertirlo en un date con el objeto Date, pero no lo consigo, de cualquier manera me sale error.

de esta menera funciona:

```
new Date(1476154800000);
```

pero el string lo devuelve una consulta y no puedo manipularlo para quitarle las comillas

Agradezco las respuestas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solo tienes que hacer uso de la función [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/parseInt) para pasar cualquier `string` a tipo *entero* (`int`), te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
var stringDate = "1476154800000"; // Tienes la fecha como string
var intDate = parseInt(stringDate); // La convertimos a int

var parseDate = new Date(intDate); // Creamos nuestra fecha

console.log(parseDate)
```

Comment: Funciona, gracias.